Is there a complete class of graph transformations that strictly do not increase the distance between any pair of vertices?
I am interested in considering graph transformations on unweighted graphs (such as edge contraction or vertex identification) that can never increase the distance between any pair of vertices. Is it known what the full set of such transformations are?
